# SQL Query asks for parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters

This is my query

```
SELECT (100.0 * count(char_copilot) / count(*)) AS [%CoPilot]
FROM charter;
```

where im trying to calculate the number of charters that have a copliot.

When i go to run the query in access it asks for the parameter.

Why is it doing this?

[image: The Table I am using]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`%` is an operator used for comparison with `LIKE` claue in SQL Statement.
I think, it could be `[%CoPilot]` that could be the issue. Try using `[PercentageCoPilot]`.

Comment: that didnt work, ive uploaded pictures showing my table if that helps

Comment: Can you try `select char_copilot from charter` and see if that works. The error you see is because column name is misspelled. Can you check if the column name is `char_copilot` (see if there aren't trailing/leading characters in the table design mode)

Comment: Also, if you look at your query in design view, look on the right and see if [Percent Copilot] is in the ORDER BY field. Sometimes Access adds them to the order by propertywhen you're sorting around in datasheet view